# Add values in independent dictionaries when the values are (2x2) numpy arrays

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have two dictionaries with the same keys and all the values are 2x2 numpy arrays.  Assumptions:

- dictionaries have the same keys
- every value is a 2x2 numpy array for all dictionaries and keys.

x1 and x2 are sample dictionaries.

```
x1 =  {k: np.random.randint(20, size=(2, 2)) for k in range(5)}
x2 =  {k: np.random.randint(20, size=(2, 2)) for k in range(5)}
```

I would like to add both x1 and x2 together by their keys and the result would be a new dictionary.

So if...

```
  x1[0] = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

and...

```
  x2[0] = [[10,20],[30,40]]
```

a new dictionary value when key = 0, would be...

```
  x_total[0] = [[11,22],[33,44]]
```

The next step would be to do this for many dictionaries with this structure.  I was thinking of doing this in a for loop, but If there are more efficient solutions, I'd love to learn about them.

I've tried the approach below using the collections library

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(x1[0])
b = Counter(x2[0])
c = dict(a + b)
```

but I think this may not apply if the values are arrays.

I also know that `np.add(x1[0], x2[0])` will result in the addition of the arrays but I'd like to do it across all keys at once.. if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: x1.get(k,0) + x2.get(k,0) for k in set(x1)}
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

x1 =  {k: np.random.randint(20, size=(2, 2)) for k in range(5)}
x2 =  {k: np.random.randint(20, size=(2, 2)) for k in range(5)}
```

Yields:

```
{0: array([[12, 15],
       [ 0,  3]]), 1: array([[ 3,  7],
       [ 9, 19]]), 2: array([[18,  4],
       [ 6, 12]]), 3: array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 7, 14]]), 4: array([[17,  5],
       [13,  8]])}

{0: array([[ 9, 19],
       [16, 19]]), 1: array([[ 5, 15],
       [15,  0]]), 2: array([[18,  3],
       [17, 19]]), 3: array([[19, 19],
       [14,  7]]), 4: array([[0, 1],
       [9, 0]])}
```

Then applying our solution, we get:

```
{0: array([[21, 34],
       [16, 22]]), 1: array([[ 8, 22],
       [24, 19]]), 2: array([[36,  7],
       [23, 31]]), 3: array([[20, 25],
       [21, 21]]), 4: array([[17,  6],
       [22,  8]])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all dictionaries are complete (they all have the same keys) a dict comprehension should be an efficient solution:

```
 x3 = {key: sum(x1[key] + x2[key]) for key in x1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using shorter datastructures for readability and assume that `x1` and `x2` share the same keys.

```
>>> x1 = {k:np.arange(k, k+2) for k in range(2)}
>>> x2 = {k:np.arange(k+1, k+3) for k in range(2)}
>>> 
>>> x1
{0: array([0, 1]), 1: array([1, 2])}
>>> x2
{0: array([1, 2]), 1: array([2, 3])}
>>>
>>> x_total = {k: x1[k] + x2[k] for k in x1}
>>> x_total
{0: array([1, 3]), 1: array([3, 5])}
```

Note that dictionaries with consecutive integer keys, especially when they start from zero, are a waste of memory (sparseness) and time (hashing). Why not use an array into which you can index with integers much more efficiently?